# It seems SELECT MAX([ColumnName]) returns value from deleted records if [ColumnName] is auto increment int type

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server or maybe other databases, if a column is auto increment int type, the table can remember the highest value even if the record has been deleted.Let's say you have a table whose with some records previously deleted, and then you use SELECT MAX([ColumnName]), it might return a value associated with a deleted record. Has anyone seen scenarios like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not happen with `SELECT MAX` (*as can be seen from the below script*) in Sql Server.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
        ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
        Val INT
)

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Val) SELECT 1
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Val) SELECT 2
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Val) SELECT 3
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Val) SELECT 4
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (Val) SELECT 5

DELETE FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE Val >= 3

SELECT  MAX(ID) MaxID
FROM    TEST_TABLE

DROP TABLE TEST_TABLE
```

Output

```
MaxID
2
```

If you were looking for the Tables Identity Value, see @AdaTheDev answer.

Comment: Hi, my knowledge of SQL is limited and I can't quite understand your script. How do I get the max value of a primary key among the existing records? Since Select Max() can return a deleted record, I can't use it for this purpose.

Comment: It will not return a deleted record. That is what this script shows you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's by design. Used IDENTITY values are not re-assigned when a record is deleted.
To get the last identity value assigned, you'd need to use [IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), which (quote)

> Returns the last identity value generated for a specified table or view. The last identity value generated can be for any session and any scope.

e.g.

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that if you're taking the MAX() on an identity/auto-increment column, then you're doing something wrong.

As @astander says, it's not behaviour I've observed under SQL Server.

You should treat such identifiers as opaque - that they happen to be structured as an integer is a mere convenience to you, with well known storage requirements, clustering behaviours, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is dev (not sysadmin's or DBA's) board - don't do this in production!

To check what is the next ID:

```
  DBCC CHECKIDENT ('YourTableName', NORESEED)
```

Note that your next ID will be @MaxID+1:

```
  DECLARE @MaxID INT;  
  SELECT @MaxID = COUNT(ID) FROM YourTableName;  
  DBCC CHECKIDENT('YourTableName', RESEED, @MaxID);
```